# How to kill a process reliably while testing?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a couple of different scripts that require opening a MongoDB instance that go something like this:

```
mongod = Popen(
        ["mongod", "--dbpath", '/path/to/db'],
    )

#Do some stuff

mongod.terminate()
```

And this works great when the code I'm executing works, but while I'm tinkering, errors inevitably arise. Then the Mongod instance remains running, and the next time I attempt to run the script, it detects that and doesn't open a new one.

I can terminate the process from the command line, but this is somewhat tedious. Or I can wrap everything in a `try` loop, but for some of the scripts, I have to do this a bunch, since every function depends on every other one. Is there a more elegant way to force close the process even in the event of an error somewhere else in the code?

EDIT: Did some testing based on tdelaney's comment, it looks like when I run these scripts in Sublime text and en error is generated, the script doesn't actually finish - it hits the error and then waits with the mongod instance open... i think. Once I kill the process in the terminal, sublime text tells me `"finished in X seconds with exit code1"`

EDIT2: On Kirby's suggestion, tried:

```
def testing():   
    mongod = Popen(
            ["mongod", "--dbpath", '/Users/KBLaptop/computation/db/'],
        )

    #Stuff that generates error

    mongod.terminate()

def cleanup():
    for proc in subprocess._active[:]:
        try: proc.terminate()
        except: pass

atexit.register(cleanup)
testing()
```

The error in `testing()` seems to prevent anything from continuing, so the `atexit` never registers and the process keeps running. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You could maintain a global list of active processes and register an `atexit` handler that kills them. You could even monkey-patch `subprocess` with a new `Popen` that does it.

Comment: @tdelaney would you be willing to elaborate a bit - I'm still a newb. Looked at the docs for `atexit` and it looks like that will be the right call, but don't really understand how to implement it. I tried putting the above code in a function and calling `atexit.register(func())`, also just putting `atexit.register(mongod)` at the end of the script, or `atexit.register(mongod.terminate())`... clearly I don't understand what it's doing.

Comment: @tdelaney actually - maybe atexit isn't the best way to go... see my edit (short version: the script seems to spit the error, but not actually exit until I kill it in the terminal)

Answer (score 3):

If you're running under CPython, you can cheat and take advantage of Python's destructors:

```
class PopenWrapper(object):
    def __del__(self):
        if self._child_created:
            self.terminate()
```

This is slightly ucky, though. My preference would be to `atexit`:

```
import atexit
mongod = Popen(...)
def cleanup():
    for proc in subprocess._active[:]:
        try: proc.terminate()
        except: pass
atexit.register(cleanup)
```

Still slightly hack-ish, though.

**EDIT:** Try this:

```
from subprocess import Popen
import atexit

started = []

def auto_popen(*args, **kw):
    p = Popen(*args, **kw)
    started.append(p)
    return p

def testing():
    mongod = auto_popen(['blah blah'], shell=True)
    assert 0

    #Stuff that generates error

    mongod.terminate()

def cleanup():
    for proc in started:
        if proc.poll() is None:
            try: proc.kill()
           except: pass

atexit.register(cleanup)
testing()
```

Comment: In that second bit of code, where's the `atexit` come in?

Comment: Just tried the second part - I'm running into the same problem I have in the edit above. Namely, the process never finishes. Whether I put the call for `cleanup()` after the original function, or I do `atexit.register(cleanup())`, the code never gets to the cleanup function, so the process stays open. I'm not running under CPython, at least not that I know of.

Comment: @kevbonham You're supposed to pass the function without calling it. Also, if your Python doesn't say IronPython, PyPy, or Jython, then you're using CPython. It doesn't explicitly say CPython.

Comment: Ah, got it - thanks for the explanation. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to fix things, see my edit #2.

Comment: @kevbonham You need to put the `atexit` call before anything else happens or any processes are created.

Comment: Changed it in my edit about (call `atexit.register(cleanup)` first, and then run `test()`, but it still leaves the process open :-(. Thanks for taking the time on this - sorry if I'm being dense about something - it just seems like there's never an exit. I get a key error (or whatever), and Mongod stays open

Comment: Copied your code in - still have the same problem. But, it's not what I thought (that it's not exiting). If I add a print statement at the start of the `cleanup()` function, it executes even before I kill in terminal, suggesting that the cleanup is running. But evidently `proc.poll()` is in fact `None` when i print it (and the `if` statement doesn't trigger). In the for loop, `print proc` returns `<subprocess.Popen object at 0x10cb93dd0>`

Again, thank you for spending so much time on this - totally understand if you move on without this getting solved.

Comment: @kevbonham Ack, I think I wrote the if statement backwards. Try `if proc.poll() is None` instead.

Comment: Ack! Sorry for not following up. No, it didn't work, though I don't recall if I trued your final suggestion. I was under time crunch and was spending too much time on this, so I ended up just opening mongod from terminal before running the scripts and closing it when I'm all done. I will have to come back to this eventually though...